# Creating multiple plot using for loop from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure which contains 9 subplots (3 x 3). X, and Y axis data is coming from the dataframe using groupby. Here is my code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3)
for index,cause in enumerate(cause_list):


    df[df['CAT']==cause].groupby('RYQ')['NO_CONSUMERS'].mean().axs[index].plot()
    axs[index].set_title(cause)



plt.show()
```

However, it does not produce the desired output. In fact it returned the error. If I remove the `axs[index]`before `plot()` and put inside the `plot()` function like `plot(ax=axs[index])`  then it worked and produces nine subplot but did not display the data in it (as shown in the figure).
[image]

Could anyone guide me where am I making the mistake?

Comment: What is your cause_list?

Comment: Cause_list filter the data frame. There are nine types of data present in the data frame. I want to show each type of data in each subplot

Comment: `print(df[df['CAT']==cause].groupby('RYQ')['NO_CONSUMERS'].mean())` in the loop and check the output

Comment: @Pygirl As I said dataframe is quiet long, I am pasting one type of data from the output:

Comment: RYQ
2016Q1    214.919355
2016Q2    199.676471
2016Q3    230.043956
2016Q4    126.526316
2017Q1    108.934426
2017Q2    136.833333
2017Q3    172.555556
2017Q4    128.937500
2018Q1    198.485714
2018Q2    207.425000
2018Q3    297.958333
2018Q4    113.630769
2019Q1    243.130435
2019Q2    190.400000
2019Q3    197.769231
2019Q4    140.152542
2020Q1    221.043478
2020Q2     75.458333
2020Q3    199.451613
2020Q4    203.937500
Freq: Q-MAR, Name: NO_CONSUMERS, dtype: float64

Comment: Can you check by manually putting graph in one on the subplot? `axs[0,1]` in `.mean().axs[index].plot()`. I guess you are not able to access those axes correctly. your axs will take two parameter one is row and second is column. Check whether you are able to see any graph in row 1, column 2 by using `axs[0,1]`. The problem must be here only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten `axs` otherwise it is a 2d array. And you can provide the ax in plot function, see [documentation of pandas plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), so using an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cause_list = np.arange(9)

df = pd.DataFrame({'CAT':np.random.choice(cause_list,100),
                  'RYQ':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],100),
                  'NO_CONSUMERS':np.random.normal(0,1,100)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(8,6))
axs = axs.flatten()
for index,cause in enumerate(cause_list):

    df[df['CAT']==cause].groupby('RYQ')['NO_CONSUMERS'].mean().plot(ax=axs[index])
    axs[index].set_title(cause)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]